# Word File corrupted while editing in Virtualbox guest (Windows7)

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery

I am a Ubuntu user and I have installed Windows7 in my Virtualbox as guest OS. I also have a shared folder b/w guest amd main OS. I started editing a MS-Word file (in shared folder) through my Virtualbox guest (Windows7). For some unknown reason Virtualbox showed some error and became unresponsive. I was able to access the file from my OS (Ubuntu 18.10). After my work was completed, I restarted Ubuntu and later I found that my word file was showing some symbolic matter and reduced to 1.5 kb size.

Now, how to recover my text in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use the included recovery options in Microsoft Word as it should be saving a backup copy often.

Comment: I tried and got no success.... MS Word is in guest OS which was accessible after uploading a .vdi file.... it showed that a file needs to be recovered but it could not read it.